# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "..." referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, oop

I am actually new to programming and I have no clue about this error. I know this type of question has been answered before but I couldn't find an answer for my problem .

> *The error is : " 1>a4main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl operator==(class EAN const &,class EAN const *)" (??8@YA_NABVEAN@@PBV0@@Z) referenced in function _main
>   "*
>
> > 1>C:\Users\LUV\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\a4\Debug\a4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>
> ```
> **main file (a4main.cpp)**
> ```
>
> > This is just a portion of the main program and I think the problem is here. If required I will post the whole main function later.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "GS1Prefix.h"
#include "Order.h"
#define MAXORDERS 100

char menu(std::istream& is);
bool style(std::istream& is, char&);

int main() {
    char choice;
    int noOrders = 0;
    iOrder* order[MAXORDERS];
    Prefix prefix("prefixRanges.txt");

    std::cout << "Bookstore Order Processor\n"
        << "=========================\n";

    // process user input
    do {
        choice = menu(std::cin);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        switch (choice) {
        case 'P':
        {
                    EAN ean;
                    if (ean.read(std::cin, prefix)) {
                        int index = -1, created = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < noOrders && index == -1; i++)
                        if (ean == order[i]->getEAN())
                            index = i;
                        if (index == -1)
                        if (noOrders < MAXORDERS) {
                            index = noOrders;
                            order[noOrders++] = new Order(ean);
                            created = true;
                        }
                        else
                            std::cerr << "No space for more orders!" << std::endl;
                        if (!order[index]->add(std::cin) && created)
                            delete order[--noOrders];
                    }
        }
```

> EAN.cpp file which contains the definition of '== operator'

```
bool operator==(const EAN& left, const EAN& right)
{


    int flag = 0;

    if (!strcmp(left.prefixele,right.prefixele))
    {

        if (!strcmp(left.area,right.area))
        {

            if (!strcmp(left.publisher,right.publisher))
            {
                if (!strcmp(left.title,right.title))
                {

                    if (left.checkdigit == right.checkdigit)
                    {

                        flag = 1;

                    }



                }

            }
        }
    }



    if (flag == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

> Order.h file

```
#include "EAN.h"


class iOrder{

public:
    virtual bool add(std::istream&) = 0;
    virtual void display(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
    virtual bool add(int n) = 0;
    virtual EAN* getEAN() = 0;
    virtual bool receive(std::istream&) = 0;
    virtual int outstanding() const = 0;

};

class Order: public iOrder
{
    int ordered;
    int delivered;
    EAN ean_o;
    bool empty;

public:

    Order();
    Order(const EAN& );
    EAN* getEAN();
    int outstanding() const;
    bool add(std::istream& is);
    bool add(int n);
    bool receive(std::istream& is);
    void display(std::ostream& os) const;
    //virtual ~Order();


};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const iOrder& order);

class SpecialOrder :public Order
{
    char* instructions;
public:
    SpecialOrder();
    SpecialOrder(const EAN& isbn, const char* instr);
    SpecialOrder(const SpecialOrder& source);
    SpecialOrder& operator=(const SpecialOrder& source);
    bool add(std::istream& is);
    void display(std::ostream& os) const;
    ~SpecialOrder();

};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const SpecialOrder& order);
```

> EAN * getEAN() function

```
EAN* Order::getEAN()
{
    EAN p = (*this).ean_o;
    EAN* pp = &p;
    return pp;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator expects two `EAN` arguments passed by reference. However, the `getEAN` method that you use as the second parameter passes a pointer to an `EAN`, not a reference. Either modify your `==` operator to accept a pointer as the second parameter, or change the code to pass two `EAN`s by reference.

Comment: I changed the EAN& right to EAN* right but then i don't know how to acess the private data members of the EAN class with a EAN* right . I mean it's a pointer of EAN type but how do I use it to acess the data members

Answer (score 1):

The function GetEAN is returning a pointer so the line

```
if (ean == order[i]->getEAN())
```

Is actually trying to compare an EAN object against a memory address

Changing the line to

```
if (ean == *( order[i]->getEAN() ) )
```

Should fix the issue as you initialize a reference via the value of an object